# Spring remoting proxy injection to a spring defined FXMLController in initialization throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, javafx, rmi, spring-remoting

As the title says, i have a server application which defines a RmiServiceExporter like this:

```
@Bean
    RmiServiceExporter exporter() {
        Class<Service> serviceInterface = Service.class;

        RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
        exporter.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);
        exporter.setService(service());
        exporter.setServiceName("Service");//serviceInterface.getSimpleName());
        exporter.setRegistryPort(1099);

        return exporter;
    }
```

and a client application, in which i have a spring configured loginScene and the RmiProxyFactoryBean.

This is the Client Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public Stage primaryStage() {
        return new Stage();
    }

    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean service() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactory = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiProxyFactory.setServiceUrl("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Service");
        rmiProxyFactory.setServiceInterface(Service.class);
        return rmiProxyFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Scene loginScene(){
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLs/LoginFXML.fxml"));
        try {
            return new Scene(loader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the LoginController, i have an initialization method, which tries to get the service bean from the ApplicationContext, but instead NoSuchBeanDefinitionException is thrown.

Here is the LoginController:

```
@Data
public class LoginController {
    private ApplicationContext factory;
    private Service service;

    @FXML private TextField textfield_username;
    @FXML private PasswordField textfield_password;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("Configurations.ClientConfig");
        service = (Service) factory.getBean("service");
    }

    @FXML
    private void textUsernameKeypressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        onEnterLogin(keyEvent);
    }

    @FXML
    private void textPasswordKeypressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        onEnterLogin(keyEvent);
    }

    @FXML
    private void buttonKeypressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        onEnterLogin(keyEvent);
    }

    private void onEnterLogin(KeyEvent keyEvent){
        if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
            login();
    }

    @FXML
    private void loginButtonPressed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        login();
    }

    private void login(){
        try {
            service.login(textfield_username.getText(), textfield_password.getText());
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Login succesfull");
            alert.show();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Login failed: " + e.getMessage());
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the exception stacktrace:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/lib/idea_rt.jar=38303:/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/bobby/Faculta/CurseAutobuze/Client/out/production/classes:/home/bobby/Faculta/CurseAutobuze/Client/out/production/resources:/home/bobby/Faculta/CurseAutobuze/Common/out/production/classes:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.18/557d13dcb647038dc687390711ccb5c9b3ffbd60/lombok-1.16.18.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.5.RELEASE/51b2e315174e32b4c8a4841a147002555add076c/spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.13.Final/830492a74b3013ef75135ea4120b2ac23fa7ad9f/hibernate-core-5.2.13.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/6.0.7.Final/9e923bb3f45e7e4c7555677f0aab7953d4ea1251/hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.1/b7f61848ac43ae9fa6e38935bfd75628b7fc9086/postgresql-42.2.1.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/2.0.5.RELEASE/f5357c650f63f3a187d3d4086a9e9132f33851a6/spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.0.4.RELEASE/dc83e08ecdb4ab28339f87358b53d75b4a8d1b9/spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.4.RELEASE/3e76d08c851113077642c5704f0f94d5ce58e905/spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.4.RELEASE/f8e029e54c0267dadb6b9f713f3feb54ec4f3a0e/spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.4.RELEASE/6b5ac0db11d81d6319ebd0bb253b2f01713df3ab/spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.0.4.RELEASE/7afc193c5d2b812ee6d2ccaf6fcc81fb83bfb4a7/spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.0.4.RELEASE/7a8c3d48d4c33621e64d1399721d8e067450fcbd/spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.0.4.RELEASE/4bda161f2e34c1486f2527a23eb47293567f473c/spring-expression-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.4.RELEASE/2221a957b5561a34f044350ba4e30ef5870254a3/spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.12/afaa5bdae313ed3ea119eb26c8848fca21e8b04e/aspectjrt-1.8.12.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/71e1cff3fcb20d3b3af4f3363c3ddb24d33c6879/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.7.Final/8b9d9c7ec8c73963ea0fe81912fc67711a4ef76/hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final/c46217ab74b532568c0ed31dc599db3048bd1b67/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.22.0-GA/3e83394258ae2089be7219b971ec21a8288528ad/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/4441f144a2a1f46ed48fcc6b476a4b6295e6d524/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/bfc4d6257dbff7a33a357f0de116be6ff951d849/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/2ad2fd09dcf5607ca96f8ef432096a96986c40a/classmate-1.3.1.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.4.RELEASE/3053e2bad0a18571bdbb9596ce51f9d458f5934f/spring-jcl-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/bobby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar Main
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/bobby/Faculta/CurseAutobuze/Client/out/production/resources/FXMLs/LoginFXML.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at Configurations.ClientConfig.loginScene(ClientConfig.java:32)
    at Configurations.ClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5da32339.CGLIB$loginScene$2(<generated>)
    at Configurations.ClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5da32339$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e0e4f3e3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at Configurations.ClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5da32339.loginScene(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'service' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
    at Controllers.LoginController.initialize(LoginController.java:28)
    ... 46 more
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Scene
    at Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem here was the problem:

```
 @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("Configurations.ClientConfig");
        service = (Service) factory.getBean("service");
    }
```

it should've been:

```
 @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ClientConfig.class);
        service = (Service) factory.getBean("service");
    }
```